# Passing data from different pages in Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Having difficulties trying to pass data from *HomePage* to *AddTask*. The concept is that I input the "Task" from the *AddTask* Page and transfer it over to the *HomePage* `task:any[]` array. Can anyone tell me how to do it? or even a better method to do it?

Code :

```
src/pages/home/home.ts
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AddTask } from '../addtask/addtask'

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {


  // Get Value from Post() with the format like below 
  tasks:any[] = [
    {task:"Make an App",priority:"High",status:"pending"}
  ]

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  openCT(){
    this.navCtrl.push(AddTask);
  }

}
```

```
src/pages/addtask/addtask.ts
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-task',
  templateUrl: 'addtask.html'
})
export class AddTask {

  // Give Value to tasks:any[]
  post(){
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage,{
      "task":"Pushing Task",
      "priority":"High",
      "status":"pending"
    })
  }

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  close(){
    this.navCtrl.pop()
  }

}
```

Comment: You did push your HomePage with some params so in your HomePage, just get it by [NavParams](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavParams/)

Comment: could you show me a sample code of it or post it as an answer?

Comment: Sample code in the link i refered above. Just use `this.tasks = this.navParams.get('task');` in you `HomePage`

Comment: thank you for the solution, I will try it later on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use [**Ionic Storage**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) module for that.Just store your array on it and use from anywhere which you need.

*home.ts*

```
// set a key/value
storage.set('tasksKey',  tasks);
```

*addtask.ts*

```
  // get a key/value pair
  storage.get('tasksKey').then((val) => {
    console.log('tasks', val);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Behaviour Subjects [Shared Services] or even ngrx in your app to pass data to components.

And if they are Parent child components you may also use event emitters `@Input` and `@output` .

I would suggest you to go with Shared services if your app size is moderate or if it big go with ngrx.

Check this Link for [ngrx](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx). It has live examples for the same

check this link for [shared services using BS](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) .It has live examples for the same

check this link for [parent child event emitters](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/inout)

The very first question.

Behaviour Subject implementation of Shared Service

**Service**

```
import {Injectable}      from '@angular/core'
    import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

    @Injectable()
    export class NavService {
      // Observable navItem source
      private _navItemSource = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
      // Observable navItem stream
      navItem$ = this._navItemSource.asObservable();
      // service command
      changeNav(number) {
        this._navItemSource.next(number);
      }
    }
```

**UPDATING COMP**

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'my-nav',
    template: '
      &lt;div class="nav-item" (click)="selectedNavItem(1)"&gt;nav 1 (click me)&lt;/div&gt;
      &lt;div class="nav-item" (click)="selectedNavItem(2)"&gt;nav 2 (click me)&lt;/div&gt;'
    })
    export class Navigation {
    item = 1;
    constructor(private _navService:NavService) {}
    selectedNavItem(item: number) {
      console.log('selected nav item ' + item);
      this._navService.changeNav(item);
    }
    }
```

**OBSERVING COMP**

```
import {Component}    from '@angular/core';
    import {NavService}   from './nav.service';
    import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

    @Component({
      selector: 'obs-comp',
      template: 'obs component, item: {{item}}'
    })
    export class ObservingComponent {
      item: number;
      subscription:Subscription;
      constructor(private _navService:NavService) {}
      ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this._navService.navItem$
          .subscribe(item => this.item = item)
      }
      ngOnDestroy() {
        // prevent memory leak when component is destroyed
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
```